# How to delete an account for real?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

How do I delete an account for real?

I followed

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

> If your account has never voted or posted more than once:  You should
>   see a delete option on your user page next to the edit link:

[image]
and this gave no response except to log me out, after which attempted login succeeded:

[image]

indicating deletion had failed.

[image: EDIT: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]

Here's a further instance:

1) On a newly created account, click delete, get: [image]

2) Click OK, get: [image]

3) Attempt login with same credentials, see success: [image]

[image]

showing account has not been deleted.

Comment: It says [your webapps account](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/55579/chrisjj?tab=activity) was only created 10 minutes ago. Sure it wasn't deleted then you created a new one? Was there any activity on the old one?

Comment: Though I've just tried that on the Japanese site that (for some reason) I was a member of. It puts up a "Confirm and create account" dialogue rather than just silently logging you in. [Did you see something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KUhxf.png)

Comment: Did you close your browser after clicking delete?  If not, your cookie was still there and when you logged in again, it probably logged you in with a new account

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I didn't close my browser (Chrome) in between deleting my Japanese account and clicking login and it asking if I wanted to create a new one.

Comment: @MartinSmith I assumed that is what would have happened, but since this question is only 7 minutes younger than the account, I was guessing the account was recreated rather than wanting to delete a 7-minute old account

Comment: Yes so the question is whether they just clicked through the create account button without reading or whether it did happen automagically. For me it didn't happen automatically despite not closing my browser.

Comment: "It says your webapps account was only created 10 minutes ago." That's not the account in question.

Comment: " Did you see something like this?" No. I just saw confirmation dialog, on which I clicked OK.

Comment: "Did you close your browser after clicking delete?" No. "If not, your cookie was still there and when you logged in again, it probably logged you in with a new account" The site did not indicate a new account.

Comment: "since this question is only 7 minutes younger than the account" Incorrect assumption. Your're conflating two separate accounts.

Comment: @ChrisJJ - So what is the link to this other account then?

Answer (score 11):

We can see from your screenshots that the following happened:

1. You successfully deleted your account.
2. You logged back into [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), creating a new account, and received the +100 association bonus.

It's the fact that you received the association bonus that made it clear that you actually did create a new account.

Indeed, [that account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/55579/chrisjj) says it was created at 21:11:28, which is about seven minutes before you posted this question.

This is the screen that appears when you are about to create an account on a Stack Exchange site with your SE credentials. Unfortunately it only references logging in and doesn't make it clear that you are *creating* an account:

[image: SE account creation dialog]

---

To delete your account "for real" simply delete it and then do not return to the site or participate further in any activity on the site that might require logging in, such as asking or answering questions.

Comment: "We can see from your screenshots that the following happened:

You successfully deleted your account." Thanks, but I see no indication that the account was successfully deleted. Please identify it on the screenshot.

Comment: "To delete your account "for real" simply delete it and then do not return to the site or participate further in any activity on the site that might require logging in, such as asking or answering questions" If it were possible to participate in further activity requiring login, then clearly the account has not been deleted for real. A really deleted account cannot be logged in to.

Comment: @Chris But you did delete your account. You then created and logged into a new one.

Comment: @ChrisJJ You could not have created the new account without first deleting the original one.

Comment: @ChrisJJ log in with different OpenID provider if you want two different identities on different sites.

Comment: @Doorknob of Snow "But you did delete your account." Evidence, please? "You then created and logged into a new one." After attempting to delete the account in question I created and logged into a new one.

Comment: @ChrisJJ What part of this are you not getting. **You successfully deleted the original account.** *It did not fail.* End of story.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Evidence? Where's your evidence that the deletion failed? I see a +100 in the reputation notifier, and that means you got the associastion bonus, meaning a new account was created.

Comment: I see member for 2 days on his webapps profile, which seems to contradict what all of you are saying.

Comment: @3ventic - Hover over the "2 days". It says `2013-12-22 21:11:28Z` so looks like it counts Sunday and Monday because it crossed a midnight (UTC) boundary. Before midnight it just said "Today".

Comment: @MartinSmith I will when I get something to hover with. Fingers aren't exactly fit for the job.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton "You successfully deleted the original account. It did not fail." You've yet to present any evidence for that. If you have any, please present it.

Comment: @  Doorknob of Snow "Evidence?", Yes - evidence to support your claim "you did delete your account". "Where's your evidence that the deletion failed?" The question's second screenshot.

Comment: @ChrisJJ it seems we just keep going back and forth.  All of the numbers that normal users have access to suggest the webapps account is very new.  So can you tell me when you think your original WebApps account was created?

Comment: @ChrisJJ All the evidence is in plain view above. Since at this point you appear to be wilfully ignoring it and in a state of denial, I can only suggest you go find something else to do. As far as I am concerned, you are done.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "it seems we just keep going back and forth." I think we won't go forth until someone can identify the claimed evidence that the account was deleted. "All of the numbers that normal users have access to suggest the webapps account is very new." I don't see that. The only numbers I see (+100, 101) suggest the account is largely unused. That's different. The presence of a delete link suggests 'account has never voted or posted more than once'. and that's consistent with what I recall. "So can you tell me when you think your original WebApps account was created?" Over 3 months ago.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Do you have any evidence that this three month old account exists? The burden is on you here.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Ok... now that we established your account is over 3 months old, can you confirm that [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/55579/chrisjj) is the account in question?  If not, can you provide a link to the account?

Answer (score 3):

You keep asking us to prove the account was recreated, and we keep suggesting you to look at the time stamps.  Unfortunately it seems you won't listen to anyone without database access, however, the evidence is all in the WebApps.SE account linked to this MSO account.

Presuming that this is the account you want to delete and based on [your statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213198/how-to-delete-an-account-for-real/213613#comment687712_213204) that the account is 3 months old, then the timestamps in your account indiciate that your account was indeed deleted and you recreated a brand new account.

First, this is a screen capture of your WebApps profile taken just a few minutes ago.

[image: Screen Capture of Account Profile]

As you can see from the circle and arrows, your Account is only 3 days old and it was created at 21:11:28 UTC on 12/22/2013, which is only 7 minutes older than this question.

Similarly, from your reputation feed on the same account:

[image]

It shows you received the Account Association reputation bonus at 21:11 2 days ago, which matches the time the account was created.

Based on this information, hopefully this shows what we have been trying to explain to you for 2 days.  The WebApp account is brand new (or was brand new 2 days ago when you asked this question).

If you did indeed have a 3 month old account that you deleted, then you recreated it when you attempted to login with your old credentials.

Comment: "You keep asking us to prove the account was recreated". Wrong. I keep asking for evidence the original account was deleted. "Presuming that this is the account you want to delete" Wrong again. "then the timestamps in your account indiciate that your account was indeed deleted... " The timestamps you've highlighted show only creation - not deletion. "If you did indeed have a 3 month old account that you deleted, then you recreated it when you attempted to login with your old credentials". If the account had been really deleted, that would have been impossible. Hence "...for real?"

Comment: PS See the further instance I have just added to the question.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: On sites that do not use OpenID, deleting an account would indeed mean you couldn't log in with the same credentials, and registering and deleting an account can be an involved process. In contrast, on sites using OpenID, simply logging in with an unrecognized OpenID creates a new account transparently (*not* giving you an error). You can then delete that account, but trying to log in again won't throw an error; instead it'll be like “oh, hey, you're new; let me transparently create an account for you!” rather than throwing an error at you.

Comment: @ChrisJJ and to add to what icktoofay said, there can be only 1 account on a site associated with a single open id, so the fact that you have a brand new account using the same open id means the old account cannot exist.

Comment: @icktoofay "You can then delete that account, but trying to log in again won't throw an error; instead it'll be like “oh, hey, you're new; let me transparently create an account for you!” That's proof that the account deletion failed. If it has succeeded, the system would have no record of the password, and hence would refuse this subsequent login.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: No. The point is that if there is no record of the password, it will create a new account with that password, *not* give an error.

Comment: @icktoofay: " if there is no record of the password, it will create a new account with that password, not give an error." What I see is attempted login to the deleted account using a different password DOES give an error: "Incorrect password": http://i.imgur.com/ORhiipF.png . Using the previous password succeeds ... and as I said, those two outcomes are only possible if the the system has stored my password or some info relating to it - despite that I requested deletion of the account.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: Try logging in with the correct password, deleting your account, and then logging in with the ‘wrong’ password. It should not give you an error.

Comment: @icktoofay: Thanks, but I did already - as reported in my last comment. It DOES give an error - shown in that screenshot.