# StackExchange cannot count time

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, timestamps, time

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213198/230957) I arrived to [ChrisJJ's profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/55579/chrisjj?tab=activity) and found out that December 22nd, 21:11 is 2 days away from December 23rd, 13:25. The time now is 2013-12-23 13:30:17Z.

[image: member for 2 days, 2013-12-22 21:11:28Z] [image: 2013-12-22 21:11:28Z member for 2 days]
<sub>(*I'm hovering over 2 days, not 12 hours, confirmed the title attribute on the 2 days element*)</sub>

I also checked this on my tablet yesterday evening (in UTC time) and it listed 2 days back then as well. I couldn't check the tooltip, though, as it's hard to hover with touch controls.

**Could it be changed so that only full days count as a day?** It's *very* confusing to see "2 days ago" less than a day later (even few minutes later if you registered right before 00:00 UTC), and most importantly, it's *wrong*.

Answer (score 4):

The account was created on December 22<sup>nd</sup>, 21:11. In the instant the day changed to December 23<sup>rd</sup>, it was counted as whole day. (Worth to mention we'll never see "1 day" there, just "today")

If someone will create account in 23:59 then at 00:00 it will aleady be seen as he's a member for 2 days - one day that lasted less than a minute until 00:00 plus the current day.

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128130/user3128130):

> [image]

Appears to be by design, but probably better changed as it's really absurd.

Comment: Feature-request then?

Comment: @3ventic first let's wait that it's confirmed as by design but yes, I'll support such request.